discrete logarithm over finite fields
Computing the discrete logarithm of a general field element $\beta \in \mathbb{F}_q$ with respect to a primitive $\alpha$ is generally an NP-intermediate problem. However, is there any non-trivial polynomial (in $\alpha$) structure whose discrete logarithm may be computed easily?
For example, is there any way to compute $\log_{\alpha}(1 + \alpha^k)$, for any $k \in \{1, \ldots, q-1\}$?

That would be the Zech logarithm. Anyway, as $k$ ranges over the given interval $1+\alpha^k$ ranges over all the elements of $\Bbb{F}_q$ except $1$. So the answer is "No" for a rather non-interesting reason.
